# Deleting bulk entries

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way in which multiple entries can be deleted - as opposed to deleting entries one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not have a way of deleting multiple entries, other then making a copy of your current form, and deleting the old. This will delete all entries associated with the deleted form.

This is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/15taIMNs), that you can follow our progress on. You can also vote for this feature, and other features that are of interest to you.